# Capture swipe left while swiping?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to capture when a user is swiping left on a page element, and then run a function while the swipe is taking place? I have somewhat of a solution, but what happens is if you're scrolling down on the page, and your finger slightly swipes to the left on an element, it runs the function.

My current solution:

```
function touchMove() {
    finalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
    changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x;
    var changeY = originalCoord.y - finalCoord.y;
    if (changeY < threshold.y && changeY > (threshold.y * -1)) {
        changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x;
        if (changeX > threshold.x) {
            $(document).off("touchmove", ".row");
            if ($(event.target).attr("class") === "row-inside") {
                var element = $(event.target);
            }
            if ($(event.target).attr("class") === "row-l") {
                var element = $(event.target).parent();
            }
            if ($(event.target).attr("class") === "row-r") {
                var element = $(event.target).parent();
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(document).on("touchmove", ".row", function () {
                    touchMove();
                });
            }, 800);
        }
    }
}
function touchStart() {
    originalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
    finalCoord.x = originalCoord.x;
}
$(document).on("touchmove", ".row", function () {
    touchMove();
});
$(document).on("touchstart", ".row", function () {
    touchStart();
});
}
```

I thought about using jQuery mobile, but the `swipeLeft` event only fires when the swiping ended, not during.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term for that is dragging.

I tried a lot of ways, the best way by far is to use Hammer.js.

Use the https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started Hammer.js dragleft event.

Check some examples on your mobile device here: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/examples/carousel.html for dragleft try the carousel.